# How to calculate time complexity of three nested dependent loops?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, asymptotic-complexity

Consider the code:

```
void foo(int n){
    int s = 0;
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
        for(j=1;j<=i*i;j++)
            if (j % i == 0){
                for (k=1; k<=j; k++)
                    s++;
            }
}
```

How would we calculate the time complexity of the above snippet having three nested dependent loops ?

I think
`i` will run till n,
`j` till i<sup>2</sup> or n<sup>2</sup>, 
`k` till `j` or n<sup>2</sup>.

So time complexity should be O(n*n<sup>2</sup>*n<sup>2</sup>) or, O(n<sup>5</sup>) according to me. But I know its O(n<sup>4</sup>). Where am I wrong?

Comment: You forgot about the if statement. The most inner loop will not run for every j but only every n^2/n = n time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:
    if (j % i == 0)
is making the difference.
for eg, for i=3 , j will run 9 times.

and (j % i == 0) will be true only 3 times. hence , the k loop will not run for 9 times but only 3 times.

Answer (score 0):

The innermost loop will be executed whenever the `j` is a multiple of `i`.
Within this loop `j` will be multiple of `i` , `i` times.

Now we consider every `i` iteration. In that only `i-1` times we will do the `if` check only.And then rest time we will run the inner loop with `ij` times(also we did the loop check).

The work for `i` iterations will be `i+ij`. `j` varies from `1..i` So the ersult will be `i^2+ (i^2*(i+1)/2)`.

Now if we consider the external loop it will be `i=1..n` `Sum(i^2+ (i^2*(i+1)/2)) ~ O(n^4)`.